# make one array of multiple arrays in javascript with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

i have this structure in my mongodb

```
    {
        category:['A','B'],
        info:.....,
    }
    {
        category:['A','F','T'],
        info:.....,
    }
    {
        category:['A','C'],
        info:.....,
    }
    {
        category:['D','B'],
        info:.....,
    }
```

i have to query all categories,

```
var db = mongo.db(read+"@127.0.0.1:27017/database",{safe:false});
db.collection('comercio').find({},{_id:0,'category.$':1},function(err, result_array)
```

first question, there is any way to get all categories?? an other aproach instead of mine??

second question....

i have to make an array that contains all categories but not repeat any category... in this example i have to make an array that contains this...

```
all_categories=['A','B','C','D','F','T'];
```

thank you all again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Aggregation framework for this query, like this:

db.comercio.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$category" }
);

After [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#_S_unwind) you can use other aggregations (e.g. group) to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need aggregation framework to get back an array of distinct categories.

Just use [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct):

```
> db.comercio.distinct("category");
["A","B","C","D","F","T"]
```